# Zencoder alternatives?

Tags: webapp-rec, video

I'm looking for some alternatives to **[Zencoder](http://zencoder.com/)** that are cheaper and easier to use.

Suggestions?

Comment: Questions that simply ask for a list don't work well on the site.  Are there criteria you're looking for?  Is there a template of features youd like info on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [encoding.com](http://encoding.com/)
2. <strike>[HD Cloud](http://hdcloud.com/)</strike>
3. [Ankoder](http://www.ankoder.com/)
4. [Panda](http://www.pandastream.com/)

*HD Cloud is no more, and leads to a parked domain - 10/13*